# Who shot Vader's ship during the Battle of Yavin, Han or Chewie?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

At the end of the movie *Star Wars: Episode IV — A New Hope* (1977), during the Battle of Yavin, we are witnesses to how, while Darth Vader and his wingmen were on the tail of Luke's X-wing in the Death Star trench, two failed series of laser shoots, one behind and one in front of Vader's left-hand wingman, the Millennium Falcon succeeds with a third one in blasting the mentioned ship, whose explosion distracts Vader's right-hand wingman whom, in turn, collides and knocks Vader's TIE Advanced fighter out of the trench before he can shoot down Luke.

Just after the shooting, we can see a closeup view of Han Solo, wearing a headset and shouting euphorically 'Yahoo!', which does not allow us to know if Chewbacca was sitting next to him or not, which made me thinking if Chewbacca could have been wearing the other headset and battling Vader's ship and TIE fighter companions with the ventral or dorsal quad laser cannon. Notice also that some time elapsed between the hit of Vader's wingmen and the shot in which appears Chewbacca and Han and, last but not least, after saying 'Great shot, kid! That was one in a million! Han stirs Chewie up as if Solo was telling the Wookiee: Your shot was great too, my friend!

The aforementioned leads me to ask, who really shot Vader's ship during the Battle of Yavin, Han or Chewie?

[image: Still picture from Star Wars A New Hope]

Comment: Whit that question, Han's medal is at stake.

Comment: @Ringo Mehndra What does "sitrs" mean in "Han stirs Chewie up as if Solo was telling the Wookiee: Your shot was great too, my friend!"?  That is an expression I have never seenbefore.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - 'Stir up' meaning:  To cause (someone) to feel a strong emotion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Chewbacca fires the shots at the TIE fighters.  While Chewie does not appear on screen during the critical moments, it is clear from a couple of facts that he is manning one of the weapons station.  We know this because Han is in the cockpit (piloting the ship—which is probably just as tricky a job as firing, under the circumstances), and moreover, he is wearing a communications headset.

[image: You're all clear kid! Now let's blow this thing and go home!]

Part of the rectangular cockpit entrance is visible to the left, behind Han.  The tunnel communicating to the gun station is circular and looks quite different.  The panel behind Han also matches the cockpit.  So we can conclude that Han is definitely in the cockpit of the Falcon.

The view of the cockpit is not wide enough to see whether Chewbacca is also present, in the copilot's seat.  However, from the presence of the headset, we know that Han would be able to communicate with Chewbacca even if Chewie were elsewhere, manning (wookieeing?) the main weapons.  Han does use the headset to talk to Luke as well, but that is probably not the reason he put it on.

Comment: But we can see Chewbacca just 40 seconds after the shot - sitting next to Han. I do not think he will be able to return so fast. He just sits next to Han as always. If Chewbacca is with the gun, he then must stay there to drive away other Tie fighters, at least for a couple of minutes.

Comment: ps. both Han and Chewbacca are in the cockpit, see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209215/did-han-solo-shoot-darth-vader-s-tie-fighter-wingman-from-the-cockpit-of-the-mil

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - Time in movies is relative. Few scenes before the scene in this post, it took 10 seconds for Luke to go from the Dejarik table to one of the cannon seats. Also, an accepted answer only means that it solved the problem of the questioner or it was the most helpful finding solution accepted by the questioner.

Comment: @Fazerack still we can clearly see in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209215/did-han-solo-shoot-darth-vader-s-tie-fighter-wingman-from-the-cockpit-of-the-mil an evidence that both Chewbacca and Han are in the cockpit at that moment.

Comment: Also we see that fire controls are closer to the Han, so that means that he made that shot.